# Access SQL - INSERT INTO using a Union query with errors

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that contains various performance metric values. I have a query (subQryKPI) built on the fly, that displays these metrics horizontally like so:

```
| EmployeeID | Sales | Calls | Hours |
--------------------------------------
|   22567    |   4   |   10  |   5   |
|   98321    |   8   |   12  |   6   |
|   24680    |   0   |    0  |   3   |
```

I have another table that contains the formulas for various KPIs:

```
|       KPI      |       Formula     |
--------------------------------------
| Sales per Call | [Sales] / [Calls] |
| Calls per Hour | [Calls] / [Hours] |
```

Lastly, I have some VBA code that builds an SQL query to calculate the KPI scores for each person and insert them into a table (tblKPIdata).

Until now the query was built to calculate 1 KPI at a time like this:

```
INSERT INTO
    tblKPIdata
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    "Sales per Call" as KPIname,
    [Sales]/[Calls] AS KpiScore
FROM
    SubQryKPI
```

This works fine and even works if the Select query includes Div/0 errors (e.g EmployeeID 24680 above); it just appears to filter the errors out which is fine as that suits my needs.

The problem that I am having is that I am trying to update the code to calculate multiple KPIs at the same time. I have tried to do this using a Union query like so:

```
INSERT INTO
    tblKPIdata
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    "Sales per Call" as KPIname,
    [Sales]/[Calls] AS KpiScore
FROM
    SubQryKPI

UNION ALL

SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    "Calls per Hour" as KPIname,
    [Calls]/[Hours] AS KpiScore
FROM
    SubQryKPI)
```

But it appears that if there is a Div/0 error in the Union query it cannot be inserted into another table. (I cannot use the old trick of `IIf(divisor = 0,0...` as I never know what the divisor is going to be.

Does anyone know why errors can't be ignored in the same way when they are part of a Union query and if there is any way around this?

Comment: Doing 2 INSERT queries will give the same result as a single INSERT from a UNION ALL. So why not just using the 2 queries way ? (and btw your code sample is having missing `[`)

Comment: Why can't you use `IIF` on the divisor?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Patrick. Do you mean just run once per KPI? I have already done that but in the real database there are hundreds of KPIs and I was hoping to find a way to do multiple KPIs in a single query to save time

Comment: Hi Tim, as mentioned in my question, the query is built on the fly so I do not know in advance what the divisor will be. When I do 1 KPI at a time as per my example, these errors are automatically filtered out. I'm trying to find a way to do the same thing with multiple KPIs

Comment: What does "Built on the fly" mean. If it's built on the fly then add the `iif()` on the fly in each part of the UNION (not at the main SELECT). Or... pass the numerator and denominator up to the main query and do your `iif()` there.

Comment: So basically the VBA code just takes whatever formula is applicable to that KPI and adds it to the SQL string. The examples given are simplified but the real formulas are much more complex (potentially with multiple divisors) so the code cannot work out which part is the divisor at run time

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure your query using the splt function to identify the dividend and control the error.

```
Dim LString as a string
Dim LArray () as a string

LString = "[Calls] / [Hours]"
LArray = Split (LString, "/")

MsgBox LArray (0) // [Calls]
MsgBox LArray (1) // [Hours] <------ apply IIF control
```

Comment: Hi Esteban, that's a good idea but unfortunately the actual formulas I have are much more complex and many have several divisors e.g [cash]/[calls]*([Available Time]+[Busy Time]/[Logged In Time]-[Lunch]) - That's one of the simpler ones. As you can see, trying to find the divisors in all of these formulas is very difficult. I was hoping to find a way to just ignore the errors like it was doing when I only calculated 1 KPI at a time